# How To Connect Multiply Accounts To The Client TLSharp

Tags: c#, telegram

I Want Connect Multi Play Numbers To The Client And Send Message with Those Numbers At The Same Time . any way for this?
tlsharp library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would most likely need to have multiple instances of the TelegramClient. When you create each instance, you can use the sessionUserId parameter so each has their own .dat file.

var client = new TelegramClient(appid, apihash, sessionUserId: "some unique name here");
Then to send a message from each at the same time, just do a foreach on your client list / array.